# How to test this simple method with Go?

Tags: testing, go, testify

I'm writing some unit tests, and I'm stuck writing a test for the following method:

```
func (database *Database) FindUnusedKey() string {
    count := 0
    possibleKey := helpers.RandomString(helpers.Config.KeySize)
    for database.DoesKeyExist(possibleKey) {
        possibleKey = helpers.RandomString(helpers.Config.KeySize + uint8(count/10))
        count++
    }
    return possibleKey
}
```

I want a test in which `helpers.RandomString(int)` returns a string that is already a key in my database, but I've found no way to redeclare or monkey patch `helpers.RandomString(int)` in my test.

I tried using testify mock, but it doesn't seem possible.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't mention the DB engine youre using, but most relational databases do have means to generate keys (sequence, auto inc fields). I would suggest to use these instead of generating keys at client side.

Comment: I have not used it myself, but it seems to have autoinc for keys: https://github.com/boltdb/bolt#autoincrementing-integer-for-the-bucket

Answer (score 0):

You can extract `database.DoesKeyExist` via dependency injection and supply a function that returns true first time in unit tests. More details http://openmymind.net/Dependency-Injection-In-Go/